# laravel 5.2 displaying data to view from DB

Tags: php, laravel-5

Why do i experience this error:

> syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR).

This is where my Controller is, **AuthController.php**:

```
public function showRoles(Request $request) {
        $users = User::all();
        return view ('app.admin.assign-roles', compact('users'));
    }
```

and this is where i will pass the view, **assign-roles.blade.php**:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title' ,'Show Users');
@section('contents')
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <th scope="row">{{$user->id}}</th>
                    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$user->email}} <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}"></td>
                </form>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('js') 
{!!Html::script('assets/js/jquery.min.js')!!} 
{!!Html::script('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') !!}
@endsection
```

Comment: You have used Compact in the Controller **return view ('app.admin.assign-roles', compact('users'));** . Are you going to Paginate and display in the table the output that you have obtained from the Controller function.

Comment: Looks like you're missing some dollar signs in your view.

Comment: @FrancescoGramano is correct, you are missing dollar signs in your `th` and `td` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code. Refer to it below.

I will provide you with the solution about your error what you have mentioned in the Question. The Error is due to you have not used the paginate function when you are using compact in return view.

**AuthController.php**

```
public function showRoles(Request $request) {
         $users = User::all();             
         return view ('app.admin.assign-roles', compact('users'));
}
```

And your view **assign-roles.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title' ,'Show Users');
@section('contents')
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <th scope="row">{{ $user->id }}</th>
                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->email}} <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}"></td>
                </form>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>            
    </div>
@endsection
@section('js') 
{!!Html::script('assets/js/jquery.min.js')!!} 
{!!Html::script('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') !!}
@endsection
```

Changes has been made in the view alone and it will work fine.

Comment: Oh thanks everyone, I forgot it. Been stressed out lately. Thanks

Comment: How will I do it ?

Comment: No brother, I just wanted to know how would I +1 you.

Comment: Can you brief what you want now :) I shall help it for you.. Glad to help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179773/pass-user-id-in-laravel-after-logged-in 
help me with this

Comment: If so for this question you find my answer is useful please accept my answer as correct one bro..

Comment: Have added the code of how to use the Auth::user(); onto that project.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179773/pass-user-id-in-laravel-after-logged-in

Comment: thank you man, I could learn so much from you. Can we talk more outside from this?

Comment: Yup so.. How can we proceed further :)

Comment: Ahh alright, I am just new here brother. Bear with me. I don't know much about this. I just checked the Check sign