# Pass user id in laravel after logged in

Tags: laravel-5

I would like to pass / submit the `user_id` of the currently logged on user. How will I do it in laravel 5.2? Please need help

I am not sure on my code on how will I use `Auth:user()` blah blah. Need help with this. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the login functionality like this and pass the datas to the required pages as per your wish.

```
public function Dologin()
{
// create our user data for the authentication
$userdata = array(
'email'     => Input::get('email'),
'password'  => Input::get('password'),
);
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) 
{
$user_id=Auth::user()->user_id;// user_id it will change as per the users table in your project.
return redirect('index');
}
else
{
}
}
```

Make sure you save your password using bcrypt method and for that alone the Auth::check() and Auth::user() will work.

Comment: Have you obtained the output as you requested in the question @RHAMAB...

Answer (score 0):

`auth()->id()` will provide the user id